# aiNodeAnim in Assimp

Tags: c++, assimp

I'm converting the data that I loaded using Assimp into my own, and the question arose.

I have code like this:

```
const aiAnimation* pAnimation = ai_scene->mAnimations[0];
const aiNodeAnim* pNodeAnim = findNodeAnim(pAnimation, nodeName);
```

`pNodeAnim - pointer`. Can the same pointer be contained in `ai_scene->mAnimations[1]`? And in general, does it happens in Assimp (with any other assimp types/classes/structures)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. [Kim Kulling's](https://github.com/kimkulling) original answer:

> Animations shall be unique. So when you are getting an animation we
>   must guarantee that this one is unique.